# marklogic use node.js client api query doc with sub element

Tags: node.js, marklogic, marklogic-9

I use marklogic 9 with Node.js Client Api. when I try to use queryBuilder to search my doc, I find some problem.


this is my doc data

```
company: {
  uuid : uuid,
  name : comapnyName,
  parentCompany: {
    uuid: uuid,
    name: parentCompanyName,
  }
}
```

I want to find all the company below the parent company but not include parent company.
I use

```
db.documents.query(
  this.qb.where(
    this.qb.directory('/company/'),
    this.qb.collection('company'),
    this.qb.word('name',parentCompanyName),
  )
).result();
```

this query find all the company include parent company.
I think it find `company.name` and `company.parentCompany.name`.
How can I use BuilderQuery to find doc with `company.parentCompany.name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to specify a scope for the query:

```
db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.directory('/company/'),
    qb.collection('company'),
    qb.scope('parentCompany', qb.word('name',parentCompanyName))
  )
).result();
```

This query matches the `name` property anywhere under the `parentCompany` property.  Such queries are equivalent to the `cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery()` function in server-side JavaScript. For more information about the scope  query builder function, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#scope

The path range index alternative specifies an explicit path instead of a scope relationship. If the scope relationship is not enough to eliminate false positives, that's the right way to go. As Wagner notes, the prerequisite is an additional index.  The query would resemble the following:

```
db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.directory('/company/'),
    qb.collection('company'),
    qb.word(qb.pathIndex('company/parentCompany/name'),parentCompanyName)
  )
).result();
```

For more information about the pathIndex query builder function, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#pathIndex

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I try `qb.scope` but it doesn't work. then, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125093/marklogic-data-do-not-comply-with-query).
I add `withOptions({search:'filtered'})` It final work. `qb.pathIndex` still not work.Should I set anything to database?like Path Range Indexes.

Comment: Yes, a path index query only works if a path range index exists. Is the scope query not working because of false positives?  If so, turning on indexing of element value positions in the database configuration might remove the need to filter. Filtering is fine for experimentation and a small result set but doesn't scale to huge result sets.

Comment: `qb.pathIndex` still not work, but `qb.scope` can solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [path range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_43733) on `name` and query with [pathRangeQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.pathRangeQuery) to get your documents.
Your path range index would look similar to this:

- scalar type: string
- path expression: company/parentCompany/name

You can add a path range index in your admin interface under databases/your-db/Path Range Indexes.

After adding the index, this xquery should get your documents:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), 
  cts:and-query((
    cts:path-range-query("company/parentCompany/name", "=", "Company name")
  ))
)
```

Sorry for not having a javscript code example, but i did not yet use the nodejs api.